# How to use try catch efficiently in C++

Tags: c++

I am a beginner in C++, so help me with this logic,

I have created a map and entered the data. This question is based on Exception handling. If there is error in my try{...} eg. Wrong data type input, it throwing to catch() and executes mContinueOrNot() function, but the program terminates without getting value for cContinueCharacter.

```
void mSearchForCustomer()
{
    try
    {
           int ncustomerid;
        std::cout<< "\nEnter the Customer ID to Search \t";
        if(!(std::cin >> ncustomerid))
        {
            throw (ncustomerid);
        }
             /*My Code*/

        mContinueOrNot();
    }
    catch(int)
    {
        std::cout<< "\nWRONG INPUT\n";
        mContinueOrNot();
    }
}




void mContinueOrNot()
{
    char cContinueCharacter;
    std::cout<<"\nEnter 'Y' to continue \n";
    std::cout<<"Continue????????? :\t";
    std::cin>>cContinueCharacter;

    if(cContinueCharacter == 'y' || cContinueCharacter == 'Y')
        mChoice();
    else
        exit(0);

}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: it is a user input.. i have declared it in class

Comment: Not totally relevant to the question, but, what you are trying to do is "control flow by exception" which is a Bad Idea. You should rewrite your code so a wrong choice is not an exceptional condition (which is not either way).

Comment: I couldn't understand a thing because of the bad indentation, so I formatted the code. I hope I did it right, and I hope you really meant it this way.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Is it a char array ? :P

Comment: no.. ncustomerid is int variable.

Comment: @TasosVogiatzoglou the variable declaration was missing when I posted the comment. Of course, if the input is *not* an int, there will be an exception that won't be caught

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Then you couldn't know the actual type :)

Comment: @TasosVogiatzoglou I can only guess from incomplete information - before I actually vote to close

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Come on, you are grumpy today. I'm just pulling your leg.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use exceptions in this case. It's much simpler to do it like this:

```
if(!(std::cin >> ncustomerid)) {
    std::cout<< "\nWRONG INPUT\n";
} else {
    std::cout  << "\nSeatch Result:\n";
    ...
}
mContinueOrNot();
```

Also, throwing an int is generally a bad idea. You should normally throw only objects that are derived from `std::exception` for error handling, or an object that does not derive from it for some special cases (but you probably won't need that).

You usually want to use exceptions for more complicated error handling. Typically you try on some code that can fail at several points, then catch the error and handle it at one point. For example, if a code would look like this without exceptions:

```
int innerFunction1() {
    ...
    if (somethingWentWrong()) {
        return SOME_ERROR;
    }
    ...
    return SUCCESS;
}

int innerFunction2() {
   ...
}

...

int outerFunction1() {
    int errorCode;
    if ((errorCode = innerFunction1()) != SUCCESS) {
        return errorCode;
    }
    if ((errorCode = innerFunction2()) != SUCCESS) {
        return errorCode;
    }
    ...
}

int outerFunction2() {
     int errorCode;
     if ((errorCode = innerFunction3()) != SUCCESS) {
        handleErrorInInnerFunction3(errorCode);
        return errorCode;
    }
    ...
}

...

int main() {
    if (outerFunction1() != SUCCESS) {
        handleError();
    }
    if (outerFunction2() != SUCCESS) {
        handleError();
    }
    ...
}
```

The same would look like this with exceptions:

```
class SomeException : public std::exception {
    ...
};

void innerFunction1() {
    ...
    if (somethingWentWrong()) {
        throw SomeException();
    }
    ...
}

int innerFunction2() {
   ...
}

...

int outerFunction1() {
    innerFunction1();
    innerFunction2();
}

int outerFunction2() {
     try {
         innerFunction3();
     catch (SomeException& e) {
        handleErrorInInnerFunction3(e);
        throw;
    }
    ...
}

...

int main() {
    try {
        outerFunction1();
        outerFunction2();
    } catch (SomeException&) {
        handleError();
    }
    ...
}
```

You can probably see why the second example is clearer than the first one.

Comment: I have tried out it.. its is useful too.. instead of using try catch I can use this .. but still the same error exists..

Answer (score 1):

Once you have `!(std::cin >> ncustomerid)`

the error state of std::cin is set, you have to reset it before reading from it.